# Assigning contentcontrol.range.text is not working

Tags: powershell, word-contentcontrol

I try to fill some word contentcontrols (Plain Text) from Excel using Powershell, but they are set to empty / display the placeholder text.

My code:

```
ForEach($Control in $Doc.ContentControls)
{
    write-host $control.Title
    [string]$FieldName = $control.Title.Trim()
    [string]$FieldContent = $Workbook.Names($FieldName).RefersToRange.Value()
    write-host $FieldContent
    $control.LockContents = $False
    $control.LockContentControl = $False
    $control.Range.Text = "Test"
    $control.Range.Text = $FieldContent
    write-host $FieldContent
}
```

When I assign 'Test' it works. So the control is editable and accepts the text-property.

When I assign $FieldContent the ContentControl gets emptied and I see the default text 'Click to enter text'.

$FieldContent is filled. $FieldContent as well as $control.Range.Text have the type System.Object.String.

No idea what is wrong

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: What is the value of `$FieldContent`, is it getting set to a valid string? Try adding some extra text to see what happens when it's set: `$control.Range.Text = "Content should be: $FieldContent"`

Comment: Value was just letters. But strangely enough it suddenly works.
I added the line, it worked, I removed the line again and my old code now also works.
Excel-File and Word-File are sure still the same (never saved any changes).
I'll try if I get the error back.

Could it be powershell acts strange if there are non-visible characters (space, tab etc.) at the end of the line ```$control.Range.Text = $FieldContent``` ?

Comment: Powershell doesn't care much about the characters in a string, but whether or not Word will accept and/or display them in this field, who knows. If it's working now, but not before, maybe you hadn't saved and reloaded some change to `$workbook`? Either way, I would recommend checking `if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($FieldContent)) { throw 'bad value for Field' }` before setting the field value.

Answer (score 0):

For me, a perfectly functioning p/s script assigning to an Excel cell stopped working (between Feb 10th and Mar 7th 2023).

The fix was to interpolate the variable into a string.

Eg.

```
$cell = $variable_value # BROKEN (but did work)
$cell = "$($variable_value)" # works
```